# Unresolved references in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, pycharm

I downloaded my old project from the repository and there are a lot of unresolved references now, how can I fix them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you configure the interpreter of your project in PyCharm ??

Comment: @Sidahmed, no, actually it was the problem. Now it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your Python interpreter and get Django installed. In the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) you 'll see:

> **Selecting Python interpreter for a project**
>
> *An interpreter can be made the project default when is it added.*
>
> To configure Python SDK for the current project follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open the Settings dialog box, and click Project Interpreter page.
> 2. In the Projects pane, choose the desired project.
> 3. For the selected project, choose SDK from the list of available Python interpreters and virtual environments. This list includes:
>
>    - Python interpreters, which reside in standard locations.
>    - Virtual environments, which reside under the project folder, or under the folder specified as an environment variable WORKON_HOME.
>    - Other Python interpreters, installed locally or remotely.
> 4. If the desired interpreter is not in the list, click cogwheel button, and configure the desired interpreter as described in the
>      section [Configuring Available Python Interpreters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html).
> 5. Apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a virtualenv you have to configure your project to let Pycharm know what interpreter should be used and where are its dependencies.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html

Comment: Thank you, @AngelPateiro, adding virtual environment solved my problem